# How to get equal or close to equal amount of objects with different field values from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

For Example I have ArrayList with Objects.
This objects have some field - pictureName.
One of them really have picture name (lets name them "1st type"), other have just an empty string (2nd type).

size of arrayList = M and can change.
Amount of 1st and 2nd-type objects can be different.

I need to get equal or close to equal amount of 1st type objects and 2nd type objects and add them into another (empty) arraylist. Size of this arraylist is N, and N<=M.

What is the better way to do this?

UPD: I can't set the size of new ArrayList. I just can find out this number (user sets it). But N<=M is always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

OP clarified their requirements so I have updated my code. I still begin by sectioning into two lists as below, but then I build the final list as follows:

```
    Iterator<MyObject> namesIterator = withNames.iterator();
    Iterator<MyObject> noNamesIterator = noNames.iterator();

    while (newList.size() < userDefinedSize) {
        if (namesIterator.hasNext()) {
            newList.add(namesIterator.next());
        }

        if (noNamesIterator.hasNext() && newList.size() < userDefinedSize) {
            newList.add(noNamesIterator.next());
        }
    }
```

### Original

My strategy is to iterate over the original list and bucket the objects by whether they have a `pictureName` or not. Then create a new list, and add to that list from my buckets until I use up all the elements in the smallest bucket.

```
private void myMethod() {
    List<MyObject> original = /* your code here */

    List<MyObject> withNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MyObject> noNames = new ArrayList<>();

    for (MyObject o : original) {
        if (o.pictureName != null) {
            withNames.add(o);
        }
        else {
            noNames.add(o);
        }
    }

    int size = Math.min(withNames.size(), noNames.size());
    List<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<>(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newList.add(withNames.get(i));
        newList.add(noNames.get(i));
    }

    // now you have the same number of named and unnamed objects in `newList`
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant set the `newList` size myself. User sets it in settings.

Comment: Then change the conditional in my `for` loop from `i < size` to `i < size && i < userSettingSize`

Comment: But what if `userSettingSize` more than 2 times bigger than `size`? In this case i won't get needed amount of objects

Comment: @BigCoach I've updated my answer to handle this scenario

Comment: If you're the type that likes to save lines of code at all costs, you could implement `Comparable` on your class, call `Collections.sort()` on your list (so all the items with names are first, then all the items without names), and then build your final list by taking items from either end of the sorted list until your new list is large enough.